# Efficiency of ParallelDo when a global variable./matrix is being updated

Tags: parallelization

(Disclaimer: I realize that the addition of matrices a and b below can be done very fast just by typing a+b. The code below is just meant to illustrate behavior similar to what I observe in much more complicated code, too lengthy to reproduce here).

Suppose I want to add matrices a and b

```
n = 50;
```

I can do it via a double loop in a single kernel, this takes 0.02 seconds:

```
a = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}];
c1 = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}];
Do[
  Do[
   c1[[i, j]] = b[[i, j]] + a[[i, j]],
   {j, 1, n}],
 {i, 1, n}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[363]= {0.0240014, Null}
```

I can try to parallelize the outer loop -- I use 4 kernels -- this takes 25 seconds -- ouch -- presumably due to the fact that the master kernel is in constant communication with the various kernels, updating c2.

```
SetSharedVariable[c2];
c2 = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}];
ParallelDo[
  Do[
   c2[[i, j]] = b[[i, j]] + a[[i, j]],
   {j, 1, n}],
  {i, 1, n}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[366]= {25.8984813, Null}
```

I can try to reduce communication to an absolute minimum, by introducing a temporary array on each kernel.  Surprisingly, this still requires 0.3 seconds.

```
SetSharedVariable[c3];
UnsetShared[vtemp];
c3 = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}];
ParallelDo[
  vtemp = Table[0., {n}];
  Do[
   vtemp[[j]] = b[[i, j]] + a[[i, j]],
   {j, 1, n}];
  c3[[i]] = vtemp,
  {i, 1, n}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[370]= {0.2940168, Null}
```

Again, my own code is far more complicated. But it shares with this example the need to distribute the task of updating a piece of a matrix. Updating the global variable/matrix invariably takes more time than executing the code on a single processor, even when the calculations on each processor are far more complex that in the above. Are there techniques to mitigate this problem?

Comment: Is there any chance you can avoid using `Set`, or any other functions with side effects?  Please see here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1771/12  Since your problem *is* parallelizable, perhaps it can be formulated in a way that Mathematica can `Parallelize` automatically.  Note that `Parallelize` will handle a lot more than `Map`, `Do` & `Table`.  It can also deal with e.g. `Inner`, `Outer`, `MapThread`, etc.  (E.g. this matrix addition is easily reformulated in a functional way using MapThread)

Comment: Actually a quick experiment has shown that `MapThread[Plus, {a, b}]; // AbsoluteTiming` is much faster than `Parallelize[MapThread[Plus, {a, b}]]; // AbsoluteTiming` (regardless of the `Method` setting), so my advice from the previous comment is not very good ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't directly construct the `Table`, as in:

```
DistributeDefinitions[a,b]
c1 = ParallelTable[b[[i, j]] + a[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, n}]
```

On my machine, with `n=500`, `Table[b[[i, j]] + a[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, n}];// AbsoluteTiming` takes 0.59 s, while `ParallelTable` takes only 0.16 s. With `n=1000`, `Table` takes 2.1s while `ParallelTable` takes only 0.47s.

For future reference, unlike in MATLAB or other languages, in Mathematica you do not need to first "initialize" the table, and then fill it.

Comment: It is not a bad idea to initialize large lists, even in Mathematica. See [this post by Leonid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4723969), item 3.1

Comment: @R.M I've seen that amazing post. I'd love to know the constraints on that, because IME using `Set` is always slower than using `Table` or `Map` (sometimes those methods are faster than `Reap`/`Sow`, too.)

Comment: OK, problem is that in my real code, c aleady exists and is being updated in the loop. A better example might have been c = c + a as opposed to c = a + b.  This necessitates having c available to the kernels.

Comment: To make sure I understand, given your code above, you want something like `c[[i,j]] = c[[i,j]] + b[[i,j]]` in the `Do` loop?

Comment: And, if that's the case, any reason you can't do `d[[i,j]] = c[[i,j]] + b[[i,j]]`, followed by `c=d` after updating `d`?