# Updating List with Do works but not with ParallelDo

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

I am trying to find 5 minimas for some function. I can obtain the results if I implement a simple Do function. I tried to speed it up by using ParallelDo and then my code returns spurious results. Here is an example:

**With Do Loop**

```
mytable = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10^7}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10^6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    10^10}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10^8}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,10^9}};
ele[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := (c/(a + b)) Exp[(d/e)^(-1/f)];

Do[mytable = SortBy[mytable, Last]; If[ele[a, b, c, d, e, f] < Last[Last[mytable]],
    mytable[[-1, All]] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, ele[a, b, c, d, e, f]}], 
    {a,1, 2, 0.5}, {b, 2, 2.5, 0.05}, {c, 0.1, 1.1, 0.5}, {d, 1, 2, 0.5},
    {e, 1, 2, 0.5}, {f, 1, 2, 0.5}]

SortBy[mytable, Last]
```

I get the desired output:

> {{2., 2.5, 0.1, 2., 1., 1., 0.0366383}, {2., 2.45, 0.1, 2., 1., 1.,0.0370499},
>   {2., 2.4, 0.1, 2., 1., 1., 0.0374709}, {2., 2.35, 0.1,2., 1., 1., 0.0379016},
>   {2., 2.3, 0.1, 2., 1., 1., 0.0383424}}

But when I simply change Do to **ParallelDo**, it gives me the original mytable values without any change.

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000000}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10000000}, {0, 0, 0, 
>     0, 0, 0, 100000000}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000000000}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>      0, 10000000000}}

Can anyone tell me if this is due to independence problem or is there a better way to Parallelize my code?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate.  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2727/12) and the one linked from it.  Very briefly: if you need to parallelize, don't use procedural programming.  Stick to functional constructs with no side effects.  `SetSharedFunction` and `SetSharedVariable` will kill performance if they are called with every iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, I am trying to make a function for my loop. Since I am relatively a newbie its taking me bit of time to make the new function work.