# ParallelDo errors using Physical Constant and a list

Tags: parallelization

I am new to using *Mathematica* in parallel and need help with the following code. When it is not run in parallel as follow, it works.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["PhysicalConstants`"]

num = 5;
lista = {};

sis := (
  x0 = RandomReal[];
  v0 = First[SpeedOfSound];

  sol = First[x /. NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, x, {t, 1}]];
  inte = Integrate[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}];
  AppendTo[lista, {inte}]
)

Do[sis, {num}];
lista
```

But, when it is run in parallel using `ParallelDo` and `SetSharedVariable[lista]` it generates errors.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["PhysicalConstants`"]

num = 5;
lista = {};

sis := (
  x0 = RandomReal[];
  v0 = First[SpeedOfSound];

  sol = First[
    x /. NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, 
      x, {t, 1}]];
  inte = Integrate[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}];

  AppendTo[lista, {inte}])

SetSharedVariable[lista];
ParallelDo[sis, {num}];
lista
```

The error has several lines. Could somebody tell me what I need to change in the code above to make it work?

Comment: `PhysicalConstants\`` is obsolete. You can use the new built-in `Quantity["SpeedOfSound"]` instead of `PhysicalConstants\`SpeedOfSound`. See the [transition guide here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html).

Comment: Your parallel code runs fine the first time you execute it on a fresh kernel, but fails when I try to re-run it (`Set::wrsym: Symbol lista is Protected.`). Is that what you observe as well? It would be useful if you could confirm or add the exact error you are experiencing to your question.

Comment: [See here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2727/12) for why it is a bad idea in general to use `AppendTo` and `SetSharedVariable`.

Answer (score 2):

To start, if you need a package for your parallel computation, you need to **load that package on all kernels** using `ParallelNeeds` instead of `Needs`. As a start, in your case using the following at least takes care of the undefined symbol errors you were receiving.

```
ParallelNeeds["PhysicalConstants`"]
```

---

Furthermore, the speed of sound and other physical constants can be obtained from the built-in `Quantity` system since version 9, (see [Upgrading From Physical Constants](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html)). Admittedly, the built-in system is still clunkier than I would like, but it does give access to the numerical values of physical constants in an almost limitless variety of units of measurement:

```
speedofsound = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfSound"], "m/s"];
```

---

I assume that you are aware of the fact that your differential equation can be solved analytically, so I suppose that this might be just a simplified example similar, but not identical, to your application.

If that is not the case, then you should definitely consider carrying out most of the math symbolically here:

```
Clear[f]
f[x0_] = Integrate[
   x[t] /. First@DSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0}, x[t], t],
   {t, 0, 1.}
  ] /. v0 -> speedofsound

Map[f, RandomReal[1, 5]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0000349718, Null} *)
```

In this case, the calculation is so trivial that I saw a *loss* in performance when attempting to parallelize execution, even for very large numbers (e.g. 5 million random values), at least on my two-kernel laptop.

---

In those cases in which you *have to* solve the differential equation numerically, then it is still simpler than your approach to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` with $x_0$ as a parameter.

```
Clear[integral]

integral[param_] :=
 NIntegrate[
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
     {x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == speedofsound}, 
     x, {t, 0, 1}, x0
     ][param][t],
  {t, 0, 1}
  ]

Map[integral, RandomReal[1, 5000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelMap[integral, RandomReal[1, 5000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out:
{19.5816, Null}
{9.95256, Null}
*)
```

The speedup from parallelization is appreciable, even on my laptop with only two kernels. I assume that it would get better if your ran more examples. In order to fully appreciate its effects, you will want to time a parallel run *after your first*, so you don't include the time it takes the system to start the parallel kernels.

---

In order to **answer the question as you asked it**, though, it is worth mentioning that `AppendTo` is generally a bad idea performance-wise (e.g. it is slow, and it creates a copy of the list to be appended to). If you want to collect an undefined number of results from your computation, it is more effective to use a combination of `Sow` and `Reap`. See for example:

- [10 Tips for Writing Fast Mathematica Code](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/)
- [Something faster than `Do` loops with `AppendTo`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42957/27951)

There is a small complication when using `Reap` and `Sow` in parallel, as explained in this tutorial from WRI: [Sow, Reap, and Parallel Programming](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/04/20/mathematica-qa-sow-reap-and-parallel-programming/), and in questions on this site (e.g. [Reap, Sow with Parallelize: bad performance, why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84534/27951), and [How to collect result continuously (interruptible calculation) when running parallel calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/313/27951)). In short, **one always needs to `Sow` on the master kernel**.

This is accomplished below by following the advice of that tutorial and creating `ParallelSow`, a wrapper for Sow that is specified to always run on the master kernel using `SetSharedFunction`.

Here is a version of your code that uses `Sow` and `Reap` and will run in parallel:

```
Clear[ParallelSow]
ParallelSow[expr_] := Sow[expr]
SetSharedFunction[ParallelSow]

num = 15;

lista = ParallelDo[
    Module[
      {x0, sol, inte},
      x0 = RandomReal[];
      sol = First[x /. NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == speedofsound}, x, {t, 1}]];
      inte = Integrate[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}];
      ParallelSow[inte]
    ],
    {num}
   ] // Reap;

lista[[2, 1]]

(* Out: 
{156.49, 156.987, 156.926, 156.996, 156.684, 156.564, 156.436, 157.219, 156.972, 156.847, 
 157.153, 156.851, 156.522, 156.784, 157.088} 
*)
```